# Update SQLalchemy class directly and get instance

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I want to update my sqlalchemy class directly and then insert the changes to the database and return the id that was recently inserted. Below is the code I am trying to make work.

```
Series.is_forfeited = is_forfeited
Series.start_date_time =date_time
Series.is_finished = is_finished
Series.is_live = is_live

instance = 'Convert newly updated object to instance'
session.add(instance)


session.commit()
id = instance.id
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you're not initializing your instance. Try this:

```
instance = Series()
instance.is_forfeited = is_forfeited
instance.start_date_time =date_time
instance.is_finished = is_finished
instance.is_live = is_live

session.add(instance)

# optional: flush before you commit to get the ID without
# closing the transaction
session.flush()

# also, don't use the variable name `id` as 
# id is a builtin function and you're overriding it.
my_id = instance.id

# when you're ready, you can commit your transaction
session.commit()
```